# Protractor 'spec not found'

Tags: selenium, protractor, jasmine2.0

I have been happily running tests on a Protractor/Jasmine2 framework. Now, I've started a new project and used the same framework - however, when I tried to run the first spec, I received a 'Spec not found' message. 
I have tried all sorts of things....explicit file locations, having spec.js in the root of the project, pushing to BitBucket, deleting the project off my machine and re-cloning. Running on VS Code and Atom makes no difference.

I've stripped the spec.js to something so simple in case it something there but I'm blowed if I can spot anything! Please see conf.js, spec.js and Package.json. Sorry for all of the // in conf.js - kept on stripping things out!!

Hoping for some eagle-eyed person...!! Thanks

PACKAGE.json

```
{
"name": "jl_autotests",
"version": "1.0.0",
"description": "Autotests",
"main": "index.js",
"scripts": {
 "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"repository": {
"type": "git",
"url": "git+ssh://git@bitbucket.org/davred61/jl_autotests.git"
},
"keywords": [
"Cucumber",
"gherkin",
"cuke",
"protractor",
"angular",
"selenium",
"endtoend",
"report",
"e2e",
"javascript"
],
"author": "D Redmayne",
"license": "ISC",
"homepage": "https://bitbucket.org/davred61/jl_autotests#readme",
"dependencies": {
"Express": "^3.0.1",
"angular": "^1.6.6",
"angularjs": "0.0.1",
"cucumber": "^3.1.0",
"glob": "^7.1.2",
"gulp": "^3.9.1",
"lodash": "^4.17.4",
"material-design-lite": "^1.3.0",
"moment": "^2.19.2",
"pretty": "^2.0.0",
"protractor": "^5.2.0",
"protractor-cucumber-framework": "^4.1.1",
"protractor-image-comparison": "^1.3.0"
},
 "devDependencies": {
"chai": "^4.1.2",
"express": "^4.16.2",
"gulp-protractor": "^4.1.0",
"jasmine-reporters": "^2.2.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "^4.2.1",
"protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter": "0.0.7",
"protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter": "^0.5.0",
"restify": "^6.3.2"
}
}
```

Conf.js

```
//var Jasmine2HtmlReporter = require('protractor-jasmine2-html-reporter');

exports.config = {
//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:444/wd/hub',
//directConnect: true,



capabilities: {
  cssSelectorsEnabled: true,
  'browserName': 'chrome'
},

   specs:['spec.js'],


allScriptsTimeout: 60000,
getPageTimetout: 30000,

framework: 'jasmine2',

//onPrepare: function() {
  //jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(
  //new Jasmine2HtmlReporter({
  //takeScreenshots: true,
  //savePath: './Reports',
  //fileName: 'HomeProfile'
  //})
 //)



//var SpecReporter = require ( 'jasmine-spec-reporter').SpecReporter;
  //jasmine.getEnv().addReporter( new SpecReporter( {
  //displayStacktrace:      true,
 //displayFailureSummary:  true,
//displayPendingSummary:  true,
//displaySuccessfulSpec:  true,
//displayFailedSpec:      true,
//displaySpecDuration:    false,
//displaySuiteNumber:     false,
//colors: {
 //success: 'green',
 //failure: 'red',
 //pending: 'yellow'
  // },
   //customProcessors: []

  //} ));

//}

};
```

spec.js

```
browser.get('https://mwac-johnlewis-dev.digitalbridge.eu/landing');
browser.sleep(10000);
```

Comment: Do you have your code defined in `describe` and `it` inside your `spec.js`?

Comment: Hi Alexce - yes...in the 'full' `spec.js` but the result is the same - cannot be found!

Comment: Just a crazy thought: there is no promise to be chained and/or resolved in your `spec.js`. Maybe that causes trouble.
Can you try to add something like `expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toBe('https//...')`? It would be a protractor bug, but who knows.

Comment: Yes, Yes - I see where you're coming from Ernst - I'll give that a try! Thanks

Comment: Have you tried `specs:['./spec.js']`